# StackCompare - See how your StackExchange profile compares to friends and rivals

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot

[image: StackCompare Overview screenshot]

### About

StackCompare is a tool that lets you see how you're doing on StackExchange sites relative to other people, be they friends, rivals, or some combination. Track your and their reputation over time. Compare badges held. Watch as you overtake them in the ranking list.

#### License

StackCompare is currently closed-source, but the app is free-to-use, with no plans to change this.

#### Get Started

Head over to [the StackCompare site](http://stackcompare.com/) and start adding friends; [graph their progress against yours](http://stackcompare.com/graph/) and [use the detailed comparison tool](http://stackcompare.com/compare/) to see how you measure up.

#### Platform

StackCompare should work on all modern major browsers; it was developed in Google Chrome, and while it doesn't look *great* with [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)), it should still be usable.

### Contact

StackCompare is a [Moorhen Solutions Ltd.](http://www.moorhensolutions.co.uk/) production, written by [Kristian Glass](http://stackexchange.com/users/889525) - find him on Twitter as [@doismellburning](https://twitter.com/doismellburning).

### Code

StackCompare was written in [Python](http://www.python.org/) using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [TempoDB](http://tempo-db.com/) to store historical reputation, [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) as a storage backend, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for the UI, [stackpy](https://github.com/doismellburning/stackpy) for interfacing with StackExchange, and hosted on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)